# MacOS Monterey 12.6 x86 mysql 8.0.30 won't start

Tags: mysql, macos-monterey

MacOS Monterey 12.6 x86 (MacBook Pro x86) mysql 8.0.30 won't start after install
Using System Preferences MySQL icon screen Start MySQL Server icon:
Short flash green as if starting, then goes red, not started
(where is log for this?)  Why won't start?

Comment: This would probably be better off in [dba.se] or [apple.se]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Found `mysqld.local.err` file in `/usr/local/mysql/data`,
said `/usr/local/mysql-files` directory needed to exist (didn't)
so I created it; mysqld now running.